# Tapping on a UIButton and hide KeyBoard in iOS7

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios7, uibutton, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a login screen,when all UITextField are filled user will tap on UIButton for Sign me in. If user tap on background the keyboard will be hide.

But i want to hide keyBoard when user clicked on UIButton which is sign me in button.When UIButton action TouchUpInside called,at that time i want to hide the keyboard. I do not want to hide keyboard on the tap of anywhere in the view.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: You must set delegate to self

Eg:

```
yourTextField.delegate=self;
```

Then:

```
    - (IBAction)HideKeyBoard:(id)sender
{
    [yourTextField resignFirstResponder];

}
```

Comment: It works after set delegate method programmatically in viewDidLoad.Thanks for your Help.

Answer (score 1):

Call `[yourTextField resignFirstResponder];` in your `loginAction`

```
- (IBAction)loginAction:(id)sender {
    [yourTextField resignFirstResponder];
    // your rest code goes here...
}
```

Comment: I have already tried this.I have use [buttonObject resignFirstResponder]; in loginAction.But it not works.

Comment: I have set delegate method programmatically.now it works.Thanks a lot for your quick reply.

Answer (score 1):

Just add this to the method in which you use the button for example:

```
- (IBAction)yourButtonMethod:(id)sender {
// Your operations
[self.yourTextFieldName resignFirstResponder]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just call `resignFirstResponder` on you textfield. like 
`[myTextField resignFirstResponder];` in `IBACtion` of button.